# Adapt control to its content

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have an issues with my user interface. I want to make some controls (i.e. a readonly `NSTextField` (a.k.a. a multiline label) and a `NSTokenField`) display all the text they contains, which can vary a lot (few words to a lot of lines).

I thought of embedding them inside a `NSScrollView`, but maybe this is not enough because I was not able to achieve my objective...

Can someone help me on this problem?

Thank you

EDIT: I added an image.

[image: UI]

Maybe the scrollbar is not the right solution. 
As you can see in the image, I have a "simple" attribute1 field, then a second field which contains a lot of text (and there is more text which I need to display in it), and a token field with a lot of text.

I see two alternatives (even if I don't know how to implement them yet..):

- Make the fields grow in height (but then I'm just postponing the problem: what if they become so large that the window need to grow too?
- Embed them in a scrollview (and make the scrollbar visible in that case, so the user knows there is more to read). I think this second alternative is better.. but simply embedding the fields in a scrollview did not solve the problem, so I was asking if I need to implement something programmatically too (and subclassing `NSView`)...

EDIT2:
Still having problems:
If I set as a constraint "size >= my minimum value", then the textfield grows correctly.. of course without the scroll view.. If, then, I try to embed it in the `NSScrollView` the text is clipped again (and the scroll view does not scroll)...

EDIT3: I attach a sample project in which I try to show the issues (without all the other things of my main project)
http://www.filedropper.com/testtextfield

Comment: If you can roughly show an diagram or image what you exactly want

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I edited my post with an image and a better explanation of my problem...

Comment: So in all the cases, Attr1, Attr2, Attr3 will be shown as one big collection?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i don't understand what you mean with "one big collection".. They are all independent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem (well.. it is more a workaround than a real solution):

- for the label I used a NSTextView, read-only, not selectable and with transparent background (so it looks like a readonly NSTextField but with scrollers).
- for the token field I used SSYTokenField (which I found here: https://github.com/jerrykrinock/ClassesObjC).. for my current requirement (read-only and size of the field decided at window creation) it works.. I don't know if this can work in more complex scenario.
  BTW: I read that cocoa autolayout has still some issues with NSScrollView (well.. it is the contrary :D). I have to test with the old strut and springs (autoresizing mask) to see if I have still the problem or not..

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to make a custom control having NSTextField and NSTokenField.

What you can do is, create a NSView and embed both of them in them, and in NSScrollView show them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, Anoop’s suggestion is probably good, to embed them in an `NSView` that is within a `NSScrollView`. If you want each of the fields within the scroll view to have the same width as the scroll view but dynamically change their height, though, you are going to need to listen for the `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` on the scroll view and change the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for each of the `NSTextField`s and the `NSTokenField` to match the width of the scroll view. I’d probably recommend subclassing the containing `NSView` and having it listen for the notification.

Edit:

I’m not sure what specific problems you’re running into with this, but here’s how I would break the problem down:

1) Create a subclass of `NSView` to be your container view.

2) Embed the text views in an instance in your container view, and embed that container view in an `NSScrollView`

3) The text views should have leading and trailing space constraints to their superview (probably 0, but whatever works for you) and top and bottom constraints to each other and to the superview to put them into a stacked configuration.

4) In the container view subclass, register for the `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` on its containing scroll view and when it receives the notification, `-setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:` on each of the text fields to match the width of the NSScrollView.

Comment: Can you try and be more explicit about what you’re doing? I don’t know what views you are adding constraints to.

Comment: maybe my english is not so good.. I thought it were a simple thing to achieve..What I want to do is to display a lot of text in a label. But I cannot make the label grows too much, so I thought the best thing was to embed it inside a scroll view. So for example with less than 2 lines the label is shown "directly". With more text, a scroll bar appears and the user can scroll the text...